# MySQL Query - Concatenate & Merge Tags

Tags: mysql

Our articles database has two tag-system tables:

1) tags contains:
tag_id
text (like politics)

2) tagmaps contains:
tag_id
article_id

I want to list all tags for each article (eg: "politics diplomacy al gore") and insert them in the keywords field in our search table (using article_id & keywords fields).

I know I can do this in phpmyadmin, but not sure how...

Answer (score 2):

If you want the data to be returned in the same field, then you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
select m.article_id,
    group_concat(t.text) tags
from tags t
inner join tagmaps m
    on t.tag_id = m.tag_id
group by m.article_id
```

Result from this would be:

```
article_id  | tags
1           | tag1, tag2, tag3
```

Then if you want them inserted into you table:

```
insert into search (article_id, keywords)
select m.article_id,
    group_concat(t.text)
from tags t
inner join tagmaps m
    on t.tag_id = m.tag_id
group by m.article_id
```

If you don't want the text values in the same field:

```
insert into search (article_id, keywords)
select m.article_id,
    t.text
from tags t
inner join tagmaps m
    on t.tag_id = m.tag_id
```

If you are trying to `UPDATE` the search table, then you can use:

```
update search
set keywords = (select  group_concat(t.text separator ', ') tags
                from tags t
                inner join tagmaps m
                    on t.tag_id = m.tag_id
                where search.article_id = m.article_id
                group by m.article_id);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3db74/1)

Comment: Thanks, that's almost it.. but search table already exists so i can't insert (article_ids, keywords)... Also, some articles may not have any tags.

Comment: Need a clause somewhere I think: where search.article_id=...??

Comment: @JayJulianPayne are you trying to just `UPDATE` the data in the `search` table?

Answer (score 0):

From a friend:

update engine4_core_search 
left join (select resource_id as tagid , group_concat(engine4_core_tags.text SEPARATOR ', ') as keywords from engine4_core_tagmaps left join engine4_core_tags
on engine4_core_tagmaps.tag_id=engine4_core_tags.tag_id group by resource_id) keywordstable on engine4_core_search.id=keywordstable.tagid 
set engine4_core_search.keywords=keywordstable.keywords
where engine4_core_search.type='artarticle' and engine4_core_search.id <10

That will update 10 rows....